# Organizing and moving photos from one device to another [Lightroom 4 and Apple devices]

Tags: software, lightroom, storage, apple

I am using Time Capsule to store my photos. The catalogs folder is on my laptop because LR4 cannot store catalogs on remote drives.

Suppose I transfer the photos to another drive, or I change laptop, or both. Assuming the relative path of the Photos does not change, will I be able to tell LR4 where the photos are, or will it get confused? I wouldn't wanna lose all the processing I've done on such photos.

Comment: Do you want to stick with LR or would you consider to switch to a RAW converter which works without a catalogue, based on files & folders only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LR will lose the connection, but by manually going through your catalog and right-click each directory (Find Missing Folder, if I remember correctly) you can point LR to the new location.